# How to turn off "unread messages" feature on Windows XP login screen?

Tags: windows-xp, login, notifications, windows-live-messenger

In Windows XP, if you have logged onto Windows Live Messenger at some point, then it'll start displaying how many unread messages on the Windows login screen. How can I turn it off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For folks who don't like the idea of playing around the Windows registry (for good reason!), you can use the TweakUI Powertoy to get rid of it completely for you **safely** and **painlessly**:

In TweakUi do the following:

1. From the left pane expand Logon and
   then Unread Mail.
2. Deselect the option “Show unread
   mail on Welcome screen.”
3. You can choose whether to apply this
   only to your account or for all
   users on that computer.

Download TweakUi from the [Windows XP Powertoys](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/xp-downloads#2TC=featured) website.

Answer (score 4):

Quick Google search gives this site as a result:  http://outlook-tips.net/howto/winxp_unread.htm.  Basically, it boils down to the following registry keys:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\UnreadMail
```

There is a key for every account configured on the system. Under each key, a value for "MessageExpiryDays (DWORD)" needs to exist and be set to 0.

Change that, reboot and you should be good to go.

Comment: I suppose that means that Thunderbird could be hacked to play along for us folk who have never installed or run Outlook and friends...